# CSS DIV tables emulating colspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

I thought I'd convert the "Index" pages of my project to use DIVs instead of tables. But I've run into a problem trying to emulate the "colspan" attribute of a  element.

Here's what my page looks like using tables, with the bottom border of each second row running across the full width of the containing row.
[image]

So replaced the HTML with the following:

```
<h2>Courses Available</h2>
<div class="rTable">
  <div class="rTableBody">
    <div class="rTableRow">
      <div class="rTableHeading th" style="width: 15%;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Code)</div>
      <div class="rTableHeading th" style="width: 35%;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</div>
      <div class="rTableHeading th" style="width: 10%;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)</div>
      <div class="rTableHeading th" style="width: 10%;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsAccredited)</div>
      <div class="rTableHeading th"> </div>
    </div>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableCell">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsAccredited)</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">@Html.ActionLink("Go to Modules for this Course", "Info", "Modules", null, new { id = item.ID })</div>
      </div>
      <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableCell2" style="text-align: right;"><strong>Synopsis: </strong></div>
        <div class="rTableCell2" style="color: cornflowerblue;">@Html.Raw(item.Description)</div>
      </div>
    }
  </div>
</div>
```

Running this against this CSS:

```
/*       Start      */
/* For div "tables" */
.rTable {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.rTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.rTableHeading {
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.rTableCell,
.rTableCell2,
.rTableHeading {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 2px 4px 4px 4px;
    /*border: 1px solid #999999;*/
}
.rTableCell2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.rTableFoot {
    display: table-footer-group;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.rTableBody {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

This is what I got:
[image]

The line only runs to the second "cell" in the previous row.
Even if I specify a width of 85% for that second cell in the second row it makes no difference.

If I add "placeholder" cells, like below, then the line extends:

```
<h2>Courses Available</h2>
<div class="rTable">
  <div class="rTableBody">
    <div class="rTableRow">
      <div class="rTableHeading th" style="width: 15%;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Code)</div>
      <div class="rTableHeading th" style="width: 35%;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</div>
      <div class="rTableHeading th" style="width: 10%;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)</div>
      <div class="rTableHeading th" style="width: 10%;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsAccredited)</div>
      <div class="rTableHeading th"> </div>
    </div>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableCell">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsAccredited)</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">@Html.ActionLink("Go to Modules for this Course", "Info", "Modules", null, new { id = item.ID })</div>
      </div>
      <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableCell2" style="text-align: right;"><strong>Synopsis: </strong></div>
        <div class="rTableCell2" style="color: cornflowerblue;">@Html.Raw(item.Description)</div>
        <div class="rTableCell2">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="rTableCell2">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="rTableCell2">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    }
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the result:
[image]

Why must I specify these "placeholder" cells to match the previous line?

Comment: You use ASP.NET?